# Why nginx location directive doesn't work?

Tags: nginx, webserver

Salut! I'm learning nginx location directives. Now I faced a trouble:

```
server {
    listen 80;
#    server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /rukovoditel/ {
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    }


#    location / {
#        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

This default.conf doesn't work correctly. When I go to 127.0.0.1/rukovoditel, I get an errror - connection refused.

But following default.conf works correctly!

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/rukovoditel;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


#    location / {
#        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Nginx service is running. -t output is correct.
Thanks for help!)

Comment: What's the output of `nginx -t`. The connection refused mean Nginx have critical config error and not running, not binding port.

Comment: Output says that everything is OK

Comment: Then what's the output of `service nginx start` and `service nginx status`?

Comment: Service is active and running